# Можно ли как-нибудь оптимизировать создание массива случайных значений?

Tags: javascript, node.js, оптимизация, сборщик-мусора

Вот код:

```
const startTime = new Date().getTime();
const arr = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 10000000; ++i) {
    arr.push(Math.random());
}
console.log(new Date().getTime() - startTime);
```

Можно ли его еще как нибудь оптимизировать. Сейчас он выполняется примерно за 300мс. Пробовал скомпилировать исходники самой nodejs. Это не помогло

Есть еще какие нибудь способы ускорения?

П.С. Да код выглядит бессмысленно. Но именно его нужно оптимизировать

Comment: Если на ваш взгляд этот код больше ни как не оптимизировать. То отпишитесь пожалуйста об этом. Мне важно знать. Что это самый лучший вариант этого кода или его можно улучшить еще.

Comment: С какой точки зрения вы хотите его оптимизировать? С точки зрения производительности?

Comment: Да. Что бы как можно быстрее он отрабатывал

Comment: Спасибо Stepan Kasyanenko. Его способ отрабатывает за 200мс. Может еще что нибудь можно сделать?

Comment: Спасибо принимается в виде принятого ответа) А вообще не думаю, что можно еще как-то быстрее, поскольку упираемся в скорость работы `Math.random()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно немного ускорить время выполнения, если заранее установить размер массива.

```js
let startTime = null;
const cnt = 10000000;

console.time('first');
const arr2 = new Array(cnt);
for (let i = 0; i < cnt; ++i) {
  arr2[i] = Math.random();
}
console.timeEnd('first');

console.time('second');
const arr = [];
for (let i = 0; i < cnt; ++i) {
  arr.push(Math.random());
}
console.timeEnd('second');
```

Comment: `map` быстрее оказался

Comment: Вот ещё https://stackoverflow.com/a/54485509/1016033